# How to resolve Unexpected response code 400 While POST data using API

Tags: java, android, json, string

As i am unable to post data using this api i am getting the response code of 400 so can u help me to get out of this
This is My Activity

```
String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/users";
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("SignupActivity", "onResponse" +response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Error.......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("role", role);
        return params;
    }
};
MySingleTon.getInstance(SignupActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

And here is My SingleTon class

```
public class MySingleTon {

private static MySingleTon mInstance;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleTon(Context context){
    mCtx = context;
    requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized MySingleTon getInstance(Context context){
    if (mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new MySingleTon(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return  requestQueue;
}

public void addToRequestQueue(Request request){
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

Here is the details of error

```
E/Volley: [4370] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/users
```

Here is My Postman Screen shot
[postman post data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiWBZ.png)
From the above postman if i use user[email], i am getting response code 500

Answer (score 0):

Attached Postman screenshot is using headers to provide the key value pairs. In your example you are overriding `getParams` method and effectively you are doing a POST request to the URL:

`http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/users?email=youremail&password=yourpassword&role=yourrole;`

If I understood correctly you should overwrite `getHeaders` method.

EDIT: 
Based on the comments, what you need is a JSON string in a request body. To also set appropriate request headers please use JsonBodyRequest class:

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONObject;
...
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
body.put("email", "youremail");
body.put("role", "yourrole");

final String requestBody = body.toString();

String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/users";
StringRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("SignupActivity", "onResponse" + String.valueOf(response));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Error.......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}){
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        // Here you provide the body from the previously stringified JSON object
        return requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
    }
};
```

Comment: If it is in body then what to do

Comment: Then you should override `public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError`. Please consult [documentation](https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/Request.html#getBody()).

Comment: Also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) to better understand what goes into http POST request. :)

Comment: At that time getparams and getHeaders is needed haa

Comment: Actually in postman its body only but while taking screenshot by mistakely i clicked on headers

Comment: Please accept if the answer has solved your problem.

Comment: Please edit the post with appropriate screenshot with data that works

Comment: i have changed screenshot

Comment: I edited my answer, please remember about necessary imports I added on top of the code. Do you understand the general idea behind this?

Comment: It is also useful to investigate incoming requests on the server side. You can easily observe results of the changes you apply. :)